# Or operator in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i would like to catch all numbers in this text:

> pletivo público Sinônimo 1313 Vice-diretor de centro interescolar de línguas público Sinônimo 1313-10 Vice-diretor de colégio público Sinônimo 1313-10 Vice-diretor de escola de classe pública Sinônimo 1313-10 Vice-diretor de escola pública Sinônimo 1313-10 Vice-diretor de grupo escolar público Sinônimo 1112-40 Vice-governador de estado Ocupação 1112-45 Vice-governador do distrito federal Ocupação 1112-55 Vice-prefeito Ocupação 1233-05 Vice-presidente comercial Sinônimo 1112-10 Vice-presidente da república Ocupação 1233-10 Vice-presidente de marketing Sinônimo 1233-05 Vice-presidente de vendas Sinônimo 5168-05 Vidente Sinônimo 7163-05 Vidraceiro Ocupação 1414 Vidraceiro (comércio varejista) Sinônimo 7163-10 Vidraceiro (edificações) Ocupação 7163-05 Vidraceiro (painéis de vidro) Sinônimo 7163-15 Vidraceiro (vitrais) Ocupação 7163-05 Vidraceiro colocador de vidros Sinônimo 7163-10 Vidraceiro de clarabóias Sinônimo 1414-10 Vidraceiro de quadros e molduras (comércio varejista) Sinônimo CBO2002 - Classificação Brasileira de Ocupações 411 ,7163 VIDRACEIROS (REVESTIMENTOS RÍGIDOS) Família 7524-20 Vidrador-esmaltador em cerâmica Sinônimo 8232-15 Vidreiro Sinônimo 7524 VIDREIROS E CERAMISTAS (ARTE E DECORAÇÃO) Família 2631-05 Vigário Sinônimo 5174-20 Vigia Ocupação 6314-15 Vigia da proa Sinônimo 5173-20 Vigia florestal Ocupação 5174-20 Vigia noturno Sinônimo 5173-25 Vigia portuário Ocupação 5173-30 Vigilante Ocupação 5173-30 Vigilante bancário Sinônimo 5173-05 Vigilante de aeroporto Sinônimo 5151-20 Vigilante de saúde Sinônimo 5173 VIGILANTES E GUARDAS DE SEGURANÇA Família 7764-05 Vimeiro Sinônimo 8417-40 Vinagreiro Ocupação 8417-20 V

That have this pattern:

```
4 numbers, a - and 2 numbers
4 numbers
```

For achieve that, i created this regex:

```
(\d{4}|\d{4}-\d{2})
```

The problem is: is not working and i can't figure it out why. I'm using the pipe wrong?

Example:

http://regexr.com/3cn8f

Thanks.

Comment: put the operands inside of parens `((\d{4})|(\d{4}-\d{2}))`

Comment: No need to use `alteration`.

Comment: Swap the or around (e.g: `(\d{4}-\d{2}|\d{4})`), It's precedence is to always match the first part first, then the second part.  You could also use something like `\d{4}(-\d{2})?`

Comment: @noob while you're correct, do you believe he would come up with `\d{4}(-\d{2})?` from the mere statement of his not needing to use alternation?

Comment: You will have to do something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/cI4sW5/1).

Comment: @mah: I was giving a hint.

Comment: @noob fair enough, but given that he's stuck on a more basic aspect of the problem, it would be fair to expect he wouldn't be able to apply the hint I think. Nice link to the regex tester though!

Comment: That was an easy one. I thought op will think on it for a while. In the meantime @RedLaser posted an answer. I have edited his answer by adding [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI4sW5/2)

Comment: @Fatima: When you have to post big texts make a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and add link to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the OR parts around

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}|\d{4}))
```

It's precedence is to always match the first part first, then the second part.

You could also use something like

```
\d{4}(-\d{2})?
```

instead though as that also matches what you want

*(Moved from comments)*

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI4sW5/2)

Comment: Thanks to @noob for the demo!

Comment: Hei, thanks! I will accept your answer in 4 minutes. Thanks noob!!

Comment: @FátimaAlves:Welcome. Go through www.regular-expressions.info. It's a great resource to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Swap and add /g in the regEx to perform global match.

```js
var str = "pletivo público Sinônimo 1313 Vice-diretor de centro interescolar de línguas público Sinônimo 1313-10 Vice-diretor de colégio público Sinônimo 1313-10 Vice-diretor de escola de classe pública Sinônimo 1313-10 Vice-diretor de escola pública Sinônimo 1313-10 Vice-diretor de grupo escolar público Sinônimo 1112-40 Vice-governador de estado Ocupação 1112-45 Vice-governador do distrito federal Ocupação 1112-55 Vice-prefeito Ocupação 1233-05 Vice-presidente comercial Sinônimo 1112-10 Vice-presidente da república Ocupação 1233-10 Vice-presidente de marketing Sinônimo 1233-05 Vice-presidente de vendas Sinônimo 5168-05 Vidente Sinônimo 7163-05 Vidraceiro Ocupação 1414 Vidraceiro (comércio varejista) Sinônimo 7163-10 Vidraceiro (edificações) Ocupação 7163-05 Vidraceiro (painéis de vidro) Sinônimo 7163-15 Vidraceiro (vitrais) Ocupação 7163-05 Vidraceiro colocador de vidros Sinônimo 7163-10 Vidraceiro de clarabóias Sinônimo 1414-10 Vidraceiro de quadros e molduras (comércio varejista) Sinônimo CBO2002 - Classificação Brasileira de Ocupações 411 ,7163 VIDRACEIROS (REVESTIMENTOS RÍGIDOS) Família 7524-20 Vidrador-esmaltador em cerâmica Sinônimo 8232-15 Vidreiro Sinônimo 7524 VIDREIROS E CERAMISTAS (ARTE E DECORAÇÃO) Família 2631-05 Vigário Sinônimo 5174-20 Vigia Ocupação 6314-15 Vigia da proa Sinônimo 5173-20 Vigia florestal Ocupação 5174-20 Vigia noturno Sinônimo 5173-25 Vigia portuário Ocupação 5173-30 Vigilante Ocupação 5173-30 Vigilante bancário Sinônimo 5173-05 Vigilante de aeroporto Sinônimo 5151-20 Vigilante de saúde Sinônimo 5173 VIGILANTES E GUARDAS DE SEGURANÇA Família 7764-05 Vimeiro Sinônimo 8417-40 Vinagreiro Ocupação 8417-20 V";

alert(str.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}|\d{4}/g));
```